# How do you track bounced emails

Tags: email, notifications, email-bounces

I'm working on a system that delivers bulk emails.

My question is how do I receive a copy of Non-Delivery notification to another email address?

The reason I need to do this , is so that I can programmatically create my own black lists.

Amazon SES somehow manges to do this, but how?

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Thanks,

Jamie

Comment: possible duplicate of [Explaining VERP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6004030/explaining-verp)

Answer (score 0):

It depends which MTA you are using (e.g. sendmail, qmail, postfix, etc), but most MTA's will log undeliverables, so you can get the non-deliverable addresses from the logs.  Also, most MTA's will send a non-deliverable notice to back to the envelope sender of the original message.